# Integrate Paymill into Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, paymill

I'm using Wordpress with AngularJs. I don't use a shop people can just book via an angular form. I installed this library via node
https://github.com/paymill/paymill-js

The script js is integrated via wordpress:

WORDPRESS:

```
wp_register_script('paymill', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/angular/node_modules/paymill-wrapper/paymill.node.js', array(), null, false);
wp_enqueue_script('paymill');
```

It is loaded properly. Also Angular works in my Wordpress Setup.

Then I create a payment object in my controller:

ANGULARJS:

```
myAppControllers.controller('PaymentCtrl', function ($scope) {
  var paymill = new PaymillContext();
  //paymill.getContext('613687880697af015308b1a6f864aeb1');
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="payment-group" class="form-group" ng-controller="PaymentCtrl" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorPayment }"></div>
```

Unfortunately my controller throws an error.
*Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in paymill.node.js line 3*

I think it is related to that Angular doesn't load scripts because it is executed on the front end?

**QUESTION:
How to get this working?**

Answer (score 0):

You should not call the PAYMILL Rest API directly from Angular, as this would expose your private key to the public. There is an officially supported Wordpress plugin, https://developers.paymill.com/en/reference/plugins-and-extensions/ , can't you use it ?